# enter polynomial in scilab interactively

Tags: scilab, polynomials

How can be done that the user enters a polynomial to define a transfer function,

I ve using

```
numT=input('Enter poly numerator:');
```

But this only gets a Double type variable instead of a polynomial type, 
Been trying as well

```
->n=poly([denT],'s','coeff');
```

but this says >Invalid factor.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` command supports two types of input: numeric and a string. For this purpose, it's convenient to accept a string and evaluate with `eval`:

```
x = poly(0, "x")    // seed for polynomial
str = input("Enter a polynomial of x: ", "string")
p = eval(str)  
disp(p)             // confirmation for the user
```

For example, the user can enter `(3*x^3-2)^2` and the expression shown back is

```
       3    6  
4 - 12x + 9x
```